# Specific tags; broad tags

Tags: discussion, tags

If one looks at the more basic topics, we have dozens of tags for any one    these topics.

E.g.

[kinematics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kinematics)     :
{ [motion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motion) [velocity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/velocity) [acceleration](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acceleration) [suvat-equations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suvat-equations) [jerk](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jerk) [position](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/position) etc. }

[classical-mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classical-mechanics)  :

{ [forces](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forces) [momentum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/momentum) [velocity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/velocity) [acceleration](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acceleration) [motion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motion) [newtonian-mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newtonian-mechanics) [lagrangian-formalism](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lagrangian-formalism) [hamiltonian-formalism](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hamiltonian-formalism) [hamiltonian](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hamiltonian)
[equations-of-motion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equations-of-motion) etc. }

[electromagnetism](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnetism):

{ [maxwell-equations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maxwell-equations) [electricity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electricity) [magnetism](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magnetism) [magnetic-fields](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magnetic-fields) [electric-field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric-field) [gauss-law](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gauss-law) etc. }

However, for more advanced topics, e.g. [string-theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string-theory), we have just one tag.

Are we supposed to:

- Merge all the more specific tags for basic subjects?
- Add new tags   for advanced subjects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add new tags. Try not to make them too specific, but add new tags. Try not to bump with this, work with newer posts instead of older ones

It really depends, in a way. Are there many (>10) questions being asked about that topic or physical/mathematical object/concept? Then make a tag. Otherwise, no.

Comment: Thanks. What about those tags which are synonyms (e.g. m-theory, f-theory, etc.)? Is it possible to vote to de-synonymise? .

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS Yes, if there are enough questions that will use that particular tag.

Comment: So, should I make a new meta post about voting to de-synonymise, or is there an in-built process?

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS Just get a list of 10 questions that are for that specific tag and ping me.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that soon.